# How to covert 2d tensor to 3d tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on TensorFlow and I have a 2d tensor with the shape `(50,2)`. How can I convert this tensor to a new shape `(None,50,2)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `Embedding` Layer as it would preserve information while increasing dimensions along with serving your purpose. `Embedding` produces a 3-D tensor - more information [here from official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding)